# Drupal - MySQL support not included in PHP

Tags: drupal, php, mysql

I am getting the following error on install of CiviCRM:

PHP Configuration

MySQL support   MySQL support not included in PHP.

I am running:

CENTOS 6.8

Apache 2.4.18

Drupal 7.54

CiviCRM 4.7.16

PHP 5.5.35

MySQL 5.6.35

The following lines of php.ini are uncommented

extension=pdo.so

extension=pdo_sqlite.so

extension=pdo_mysql.so

I cannot quite figure out this error and so far have found nothing in my search that leads me to a solution.

Anyone have some insight?

TIA

Gary

Answer (score 3):

CiviCRM is looking for the function [`mysqli_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php), which is provided via the [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) ("MySQL improved") extension in PHP.

To enable this, uncomment -

```
extension=mysqli.so
```

If that doesn't work, your next question may be: [How to enable mysqli in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250356/how-to-install-mysqli)